# как получить последний id из базы данных, если там ничего нет

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Делаю небольшую админку такого рода:[image: админка]

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При добавлении новой записи в javascript я просто брал id последней записи (в данном случае равно 3) и прибавлял к нему 1. Если же записей 0, то присваивал новой записи id = 0.

Как оказалось, если в базе данных есть инкрементное поле, при удалении записей, оно всё равно запоминает последний id.

1. Т.е. было 5 записей, id соответственно (0-4).
2. Затем их все удалили.
3. Следующая запись будет не с id = 0, как я ожидал, а id = 6.

   Теперь, собственно, вопрос - каким образом можно узнать id новой записи, если в базе данных нет ни одной записи?

Comment: Так, собственно, если поле `id` - автоинкремент, то зачем его вытаскивать,  прибавлять 1 и вставлять с прибавленным числом? достаточно просто вставить запись без `id`  в `insert` запросе

Comment: по заданию мне надо сразу обновлять данные в таблице (визуальной на самой странице), а запрос на сервер отправлять фоном (через ajax). Понятное дело, что я вставляю новые данные без инкрементного поля, а БД сама разрулит.

Comment: Не вижу проблем. Используя mysqli или PDO при вставке в таблицу, можно после запроса взять его `last_insert_id` .... пример http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php ........так что непонятно в чем всё-таки проблема. И это, кстати, самый верный вариант

Comment: *это, кстати, самый верный вариант* Если значение нужно "для полюбопытствовать", или если БД используется монопольно - да. А в многопользовательской среде полученное таким манером значение может уже оказаться попользованным другим клиентом.

Comment: @Akina `mysqli.insert-id.php` отдает `last_insert_id` того самого коннекта, на котором был произведен, а не другого. Вот если бы использовался `SELECT MAX(\`id\`) FROM \`table\``, причем уже в другом запросе, а не в какой-нибудь `LOCK TABLES` - я бы согласился.... но там используется что-то другое, ЕМНИП

Comment: @АлексейШиманский И напомню - автору нужно не значение в последней вставленной записи, а значение, которое получит следующая при её вставке.

Comment: @Akina ну ок `last_insert_id + 1` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT auto_increment
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'dbname'
AND table_name = 'tablename'
```

Comment: Ох, не думаю, что так стоит делать в данном случае, не смотря на то, что и можно :-/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну в общем да - ручное задание значения при живом автоинкременте попахивает идиотизмом... а в случае не-монопольной работы ещё и потенциальной задницей. Но товарищ хочет УЗНАТЬ, а не ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ (если, конечно, он спросил именно то, что хотел спросить).

Comment: сомниииииительно :)

Comment: в данном случае этот инкремент нужен только для того, чтобы добавленная новая строка была с правильным id. Т.е. строка добавляется на странице посредством js. А на сервер строка для вставки отправляется без id, бд сама присваивает нужный id.

Comment: @ТобакаловКаниет а если с таблицей будут работать несколько пользователей - то получишь такую ерунду в итоге, что потом плакать ночами будешь)